# Retrieve list of all music on host Android phone

Tags: java, android

How could I get a list of all of the music on the host phone? Not videos or ringtones, just music.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i dit a quick google search for you. the second hit:

http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/54/